# moment.js military time check with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Is it possible to validate time with moment.js when using a jQuery selector?

I tried:

```
console.log(moment($('#trainTimeInitial').val().trim(),"HH:mm").isValid());
```

to see if it would come out true or false but it doesn't log anything.

the trainTimeInitial id is an input field that gets checked on a button click event.

Comment: aint it easier to add an input mask to the input?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Im fairly new so I dont know what that is

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/FLhpq/11427/

Comment: ill take a look

Comment: thats really weird that it works in fiddle.. ima try to get this working hold on

Comment: ahh silly me.. i was setting the value in a conditional that didnt happen yet hahaha.. thanks for validating that it works tho, i appreciate it